# Screentips and Supertips are not shown when button is inside Menu on Mac only

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I have created a ribbonX customUI and my Screentips and Supertips are shown correctly on Windows. But when the button is **inside a menu**, buttons show no Screentips or Supertips on the MacBook. Any ideas how to solve that?

```vb
<menu id="ThisMenu" size="large" itemSize="normal" label="This Menu" image="MenuImage">
    <menuSeparator id="Tab2020Sep4"/>
    <button id="ThisButton" label="ThisButton" imageMso="ShapeElbowConnectorArrow" onAction="RunThis" screentip="This is Screentip" supertip="This is supertip"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: The version of macOS? The Office version?

Comment: Sorry @JohnKorchok -- you are right. It's Monterey and newest o365 with all updates. Is it generally working for you?